# How do you update 'phantomjs' package references to 'phantomjs-prebuilt' - message from terminal in Mac OS

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, meanjs

I am attempting to learn mean.js through a tutorial.

I have installed node.js, npm, mongodb, grunt, bower, gulp, and yeoman without any errors.

When I try to "yo meanjs" in the terminal (on Mac OS), I enter the directory where I want to install and answer a few questions.  I continually get this message:
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cd users/danzeller/mean/vteer && npm install
npm WARN deprecated phantomjs@2.1.7: Package renamed to phantomjs-prebuilt. Please update 'phantomjs' package references to 'phantomjs-prebuilt'

I installed phantomjs-prebuilt according to their website without errors.

I am not sure how to "update the references" as shown in the error message.

Here is the full terminal error:

```
Running npm install for you....
This may take a couple minutes.
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cd users/danzeller/mean/vteer && npm install
npm WARN deprecated phantomjs@2.1.7: Package renamed to phantomjs-prebuilt. Please update 'phantomjs' package references to 'phantomjs-prebuilt'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.1
npm ERR! path /var/root/.npm/connect-mongo
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/root/.npm/connect-mongo'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/root/.npm/connect-mongo']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/var/root/.npm/connect-mongo',
npm ERR!   parent: 'volunteer' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /private/var/root/users/danzeller/mean/vteer/npm-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:475:12)
```

It seems to want to put the install in the /private/var/root/ folder however, I would like to place in the /users/danzeller/mean/ folder.

I am using

```
sudo su -
```

in the terminal window to install this ---- is this incorrect?  Does this point to the wrong folder?

Any help would be great since I am new to all this.

Thanks!
Dan

Answer (score 0):

The package owner is in charge to do it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Node version 8.1.2(new) and npm version 5.0.3.
After I downgraded Node to V6.11.0(stable) and npm V3.10.10 it fixed my issue.

You can also try to remove your directory "/usr/local/lib/node-modules" and reinstall Node V6.11.0 if first solution will not work for you.